# How to create a canvas using the pixel data from a DICOM file?

Tags: javascript, canvas, rendering, dicom

I'm currently working on a project that deals with DICOM files. I had success in parsing data from a collection of DICOM files. The problem occurs when I try to deal with the pixel data of a DICOM file and pass it to a canvas in order to show it.

I have used "Dwv" library to parse the DICOM file. It helped me to get the pixel data as an array and pass it to function that create the new `ImageData` of the canvas context.

```
function buildCanvas(width, height, pixelData) {
    var imgData = context.createImageData(width, height);
    for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
        var x = (i / 4) % 40;
        imgData.data[i] = pixelData[x];
        imgData.data[i + 1] = pixelData[x + 1];
        imgData.data[i + 2] = pixelData[x + 2];
        imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
    }
    console.log(pixelData);
    context.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}
```

Following is a result I get:

[image: Output image]

As you can see, the output image is completely messed up. What is the better approach to solve this problem.

Comment: `var x = (i / 4) % 40;` what is this supposed to do? Also, *better approach* in what sense, what problem are you facing with the current approach?

Comment: Your trick with x for walking over two different image sizes is not correct. Just use two counters instead. it will be easier to read too.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.. It would helpful if you explain your solution or give an example..

Comment: int j = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i ++=3) {
        imgData.data[j++]] = pixelData[i];
        imgData.data[j++] = pixelData[i + 1];
        imgData.data[j++] = pixelData[i + 2];
        imgData.data[j++] = 255;
    }

Comment: well this doesn't change a lot.. here a screenshot for the result : https://imgur.com/bU9smVG

Answer (score 0):

DICOM data can store RGB data but the most usual is monochrome data. This is defined in the Photometric Interpretation tag (referenced as (0028,0004)). If you are dealing with monochrome data, the dwv library will return an array with the raw values of the slice and of size `number of rows * number of columns`. The output canvas array is RGBA so it will be 4 times bigger. Your loop could look like:

```
    var j = 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i < pixelData.length; ++i) {
        imgData.data[j++] = pixelData[i];
        imgData.data[j++] = pixelData[i];
        imgData.data[j++] = pixelData[i];
        imgData.data[j++] = 255;
    }
```

The problem now is that the DICOM data is not scaled in the [0,255] range, that's where the window center/width comes into play. Check the standard to understand how to interpret it. The dwv library also contains example code to help you.